# Many classes that have the same method or one class that has the method and is inherited by the other classes?

Tags: java, android, memory, methods, share

I am developing an Android app and naturally I have a lot of classes that lay out Views on screen. Now I have this simple method DpToPx(int) here that I've seen elsewhere on stackOverflow:

```
private int dpToPx(int dp){
   DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
   return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, displayMetrics);
}
```

I use this to provide some sort of layout consistency across different screen resolution devices. Which is better practice -

*To have this method in every class that lays out views OR make it an interface that all classes implement?*

Especially in terms of memory and object retention (AFAIK sometimes it is better to repeat the same method across classes than make a separate object). But when it is more than two classes?

Comment: If the method is fixed and only doing one specific task you could have it as a static method, which will be accessible from all of your classes.

Comment: .... in addition to MiKE comment: of course you should pass context through method argument

Comment: @MiKE I tried this but getResources() is a non-static method that can't be accessed from a static context

Comment: You could pass the "context" as method variable. int dpToPx(int dp, type context). Or you could get getDisplayMetrics() 1 line before you call dpToPx and pass it to the dpToPx method. Just like @Selvin said.

Comment: @MiKE yes, that did it, in addition I am putting it in a separate class as a static method as suggested by T.J.Crowder, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably make it either:

1. A static utility method in a utility class that your views pass `context` into, or
2. An instance method of a utility class your views instantiate

E.g.

```
class LayoutUtils {
    public static int dpToPx(Context context, int dp){
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, displayMetrics);
    }
}
```

or

```
class LayoutUtils {
    private Context context;

    LayoutUtils(context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public int dpToPx(int dp){
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = this.context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, displayMetrics);
    }
}
```

In the latter case, each view would have a `LayoutUtils` instance.

The instance method is easier to mock for tests (you'd need to adjust the above, of course, to add dependency injection rather than a direct constructor).

Comment: I think the first option is a better solution - that way I avoid creating new objects and keeping a reference to a Context object which from what I've read is a major reason for memory leaks. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I create a class "Utils" inside a package "helpers" and there I put all methods and variables I think will use across all app.

Then it just simple to call like Utils.dpToPx(10);
Don't forget to import the class :)

It's my way to do it I don't know if its the best.

A bit of code

> public class Utils {
>
> ```
>   public static int dp2px(int dp, Context context) {
>     return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp,
>             context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
> }
> ```
>
> }

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I dont have the sufficient reputation yet sorry